How Uber made their progress bar in android notification?
Uber has an article https://www.uber.com/en-DE/blog/live-activity-on-ios/ where they said they made the notification with the progress bar. I know the article says that it's about iOS, but there is part about android too. The notification looks like this: The notification, android on the right
I understand what they did in xml for notification, but I can't understand how they control it from the code. How do they calculate the progress if there is no way to get notification width?
I tried to use screen width and subtract from it some value for the notification edges (about 110 dp). Then sett it as left padding of filled line of the progress bar.
val displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
val screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels
val edgeDistance = 100dip // take it from values file

val progress = (screenWidth - edgeDistance) * p // 0 <= p <= 1

setViewPadding(filledLineId, progress, 0, 0, 0)

But the notification width is often much lesser than the screen width. In that case the progress bar is cut on the right side of notification.
My xml for progress bar:
<LinearLayout android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/notification_progress" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <FrameLayout 
      android:id="@id/filled" 
      android:background="@color/color2" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="@dimen/height" 
      android:layout_weight="1.0" 
      android:layout_marginEnd="2dp" />
    <ImageView 
      android:id="@id/progress_indicator" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="@dimen/indicator_height" 
      android:src="@drawable/ic_progress_indicator" 
      android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    <FrameLayout 
      android:id="@id/not_filled" 
      android:background="@color/color2" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/height" 
      android:layout_weight="100" />
</LinearLayout>


This is about the only thing I can think of: https://drive.google.com/open?id=16mvmV8-Rsu6c58fZvnTbMvtbktgCAbe1&usp=drive_fs. It uses a LinearLayout with weighted children that are added programmatically. Looks like https://i.sstatic.net/19NOYif3.png, but you can see where your custom drawables can be substituted. It's not pixel perfect, but it's very close. You might also be able to do something by adjusting layout margins, but the necessary methods weren't added to RemoteViews until API level 31, so they're not much help before then.
